# Need clarification on virtual functions and private members of class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

In C++ if public virtual function of base class has reference to private member field, and derived class doesn't override this method then will that reference be pointing to private member of derived class

Comment: A code sample will be helpful. How does the "virtual function have a reference"?

Answer (score 2):

The method of the base class will still act on the member of the base class, even if you add a member with the same name to your derived class (which is, I guess, the point you wanted to make).

Comment: Thanks,Is there any technique to achieve what i want here?

Comment: You could add a virtual function to get a reference to the data you want and override it in the derived class. Doesn't seem very elegent though, what are you trying to actually achieve by doing this?

Comment: actually i'm trying to reuse the code(legacy, and changes to this to be avoided) in my new class which changes only few methods of the existing

Answer (score 1):

No, if you don't override the method it will be called as if from inside the base class and thus refer to the private method inside the base class.

Comment: Thanks,Is there any technique to achieve what i want here?

Comment: @user1447725 Make the function protected and virtual?